# How to convert multi-gpu weights to single GPU model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

While loading weights from a multi-gpu trained model into CPU or single GPU model, I get errors.

I used DenseNet121 with imagenet weights, add separate dense layers on top of it due to different activation function properties of the output, and concatenated them in the output layer

```py
base_model = DenseNet121(include_top=False,weights="imagenet", input_shape = IMG_SHAPE)

x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

class1 = Dense(512,activation="relu")(x)
class1 = Dense(3,activation="softmax")(class1)

class2 = Dense(512,activation="relu")(x)
class2 = Dense(4,activation="softmax")(class2 )

class3 = Dense(512,activation="relu")(x)
class3 = Dense(5,activation="sigmoid")(class3 )

class4 = Dense(512,activation="relu")(x)
class4 = Dense(6,activation="softmax")(class4 )

class5 = Dense(512,activation="relu")(x)
class5 = Dense(7,activation="sigmoid")(class5 )

class6 = Dense(512, activation="relu")(x)
class6 = Dense(8, activation = "softmax")(class6 )

con = concatenate([class1 ,class2 ,class3 ,class4 ,class5 ,class6 ])

model = Model(inputs = base_model.input, outputs = con)

model = multi_gpu_model(model, gpus = 2)

## After training is complete:

model.save_weights('model.h5')
```

Cannot load while using tf.keras in CPU only mode. Apart from that, I'm not sure how one can use multi-gpu models while doing deployment to web or else due to the conversion problem of weights.

I also tried saving weights with:

```py
multi_gpu_model = model.layers[-2]

multi_gpu_model.save_weights("single_gpu_model.h5")
```

it works in single GPU or CPU mode but it doesn't cover all layers' weights IMO.

Many thanks,

Comment: It's weird, personally, I never have the problem of using a multi-gpu trained model on other platforms. What exactly is the error msg?

Comment: @stormzhou "Cannot call load_model on network trained using multi_gpu" while I was trying to load model with its json file & multi-gpu trained weights. But issue resolved after changing keras==2.2.4 & tf==1.14.0. Also: 

```python

from keras.models import load_model;

multi_model = load_model('your_multi_gpu_model.hdf5');
old_model = multi_model.layers[-2];
old_model.save('single_gpu_model.hdf5');

```

this works fine but I did not really understand why it works. My model.layer[-2] points a dense layer that only represents one class.